# Insertar html link en el json de datos de un Datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

tras mucho investigar me encuentro en este callejón sin salida.

En mi plataforma tengo un sistema de permisos un tanto especial. He creado un Datatable para poder mostrar el directorio de usuarios y en función del usuario que está logeado deberá permitirle sólo ver o bien editar o eliminar.

Lo que he hecho es, en mi Controller de PHP monto el json con los datos y la última columna serían código html con los link correspondientes. Me está mostrando correctamente los botones pero no ejecuta el link. Algo se me está escapando.

JSON que pasa al Datatable

```
{"data":[{"id_usuario":"1",
          "nombre_departamento":"Informática",
          "nombre":"Nombre usuario",
          "apellidos":"Apellidos",
          "telefono":"123123123",
          "extension":"1111",
          "email":"email@dominio.es",
          "opciones":"<a type='button' class='Btn_ver btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-search'><\/i><\/a> 
                      <a type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-edit' href='http:\/\/localhost\/intranet\/directorio\/editar\/1'><\/i><\/a> 
                      <a type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-trash' href='http:\/\/localhost\/intranet\/directorio\/borrar\/1'><\/i><\/a>"
}
```

El resultado que se muestra en pantalla es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código del data table.

```
        var listar = function(){
      var datatable = $('#tabla_directorio').DataTable({
          ajax: "http://localhost/intranet/directorio/listado_directorio",
          order: [[1, "desc"]],
          columns: [
              {data:"id_usuario"},
              {data:"nombre_departamento"},
              {data:"nombre"},
              {data:"apellidos"},
              {data:"telefono"},
              {data:"extension"},
              {data:"email"},
              {data:"opciones"} 
            ],  
          language: idioma_espanol,
          buttons:[ 
              {
                  extend:    'excelHtml5',
                  text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel" style="font-size:24px"></i>',
                  titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                  className: 'btn btn-success',
                  exportOptions: {
                          columns: [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
                  },
              },
              {
                  extend:    'csvHtml5',
                  text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-alt" style="font-size:24px"></i>',
                  titleAttr: 'Exportar a CSV',
                  className: 'btn btn-info',
                  exportOptions: {
                          columns: [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
                  },
              }
          ]                
      });
    }
    var idioma_espanol = {
            sProcessing:     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  "",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Estás poniéndole el atributo `href` a la etiqueta `<i>`. Esta etiqueta no tiene disponible dicho atributo. Prueba a colocárselo a la etiqueta `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fallo de principiante!!!!!

En el Json estaba montando mal el href. Lo estaba poniendo en el li en vez de en a

Código Erroneo:

```
<a type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-edit' href='http:\/\/localhost\/intranet\/directorio\/editar\/1'><\/i><\/a>
```

Código Correcto:

```
<a type='button' class='btn btn-success' href='http:\/\/localhost\/intranet\/directorio\/editar\/1'><i class='fas fa-edit'><\/i><\/a>
```

Perdón por las molestias